# SpresenseのanalogRead()の速度が非常に遅い

Tags: spresense, arduino

ArduinoとSpresenseを使いアナログ入力ピンをanalogRead関数で電圧を計測したのですが、1回の計測で15ms(プログラムでは100回で1.5秒)もかかってしまいました、こんなに遅いものでしょうか。
早くする方法はないでしょうか。

```
int sensorPin = 3;    // select the input pin for the potentiometer
int sensorValue = 0;  // variable to store the value coming from the sensor

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  for(int loop_count = 0;loop_count <100;loop_count ++)  {
    sensorValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
  }
  printf("read=%d\n",sensorValue);
}
```

Comment: 使用したボードがSpresenseでプログラミングがArduino 1.8.13です。

Comment: Spresenseの仕様のようです。6chあるアナログ入力はサンプリング周波数がA0~A3が64Hz、A4とA5は16kHzと決まっているようです。さらに、サンプリング周期の間はanalogRead()の中で待ち状態となるようで、処理がそこで停止しているようです。

Comment: サンプリング周波数(Fs)より速く読むことはできない、というか、速くしても同じ値が読めるだけなので意味が無いかと。最大Fsについては、<https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_adc_サンプリング周波数について> を見る限り、SDK Configを変更しなおせばA0~A3でも最大4KHzまで設定可能。A4~A5ピンを使えばデフォルトで16kHz、Configを変更すれば512KHzまで設定できるようです。

Answer (score 0):

http://www.musashinodenpa.com/arduino/ref/index.php?f=0&pos=2113
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogread/
によると１回あたり 100usec らしいので Arduino としては遅すぎっス。

参考までに今どきのインバータ制御用マイコンでは１回の変換は絶対精度を犠牲にして最速モードを選んだ場合 12bit 変換が 1usec 程度で可能っス。常時最速サンプリングをし続けたいなら、結果を受け取る手続きも割り込みではなく DMA とか DTC とかで自動化しないといけなくなるわけだけど。

提示コードを見るに、遅いのは `printf()` のほうを疑うっす。シリアルポートで出力しているなら bps 設定が良くないとか。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。自分も遅すぎと思い、100回に1回だけprintf()で出力したてみたのが添付のソースです。毎回出力時は1回の出力時間は数十msサイクルで出力してますので、printf()ではないようです。