# Spresenceで周期的にADCを読み込む方法は？

Tags: spresense

周期的にADC値を読む方法について教えてください。
Arduino IDEで開発を行っています。

#### やりたいこと

10msec毎にSpresence標準搭載のアナログ入力専用ピンの電圧値を読み出したい。
(Spresenceホームページ記載の"1.1.12. attachTimerInterrupt()"の項目から
割り込み関数内から呼び出し可能な API には制限があり、analogRead()ができないことは確認済みです。）

タイマー割込みに登録した関数から直接analogRead()を行うとエラーが出るが、他の関数を介してanalogRead()を呼べば、正常にアナログ値を読み取れるのではないかと考えた。タイマー割込みから外部割り込み（IOピンをショート）を経由して、analogRead()を呼んでみようと考え、下記のプログラムを作成しました。（一部抜粋）

開発ソフトウェアでは、T2_TIMEを10msecに相当する値に変更して実装する予定です。
ADCの速度について.configファイルから256Hzに変更済みです。
外付けのADCをつける等も考えられるのですが、Spresence単体で行いたいです。

```c
#include <Arduino.h>

#define T2_TIME       5000000                   // Timer割り込み 5[s]
#define BAUDRATE_Debug  115200              // Debug Baud rate of UART in bps
HardwareSerial UARTDebug = Serial;    //DebugSerialのUART割当て
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  UARTDebug.begin(BAUDRATE_Debug,SERIAL_8N1);
  pinMode(02, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(02, LOW);
  pinMode(40, INPUT);
  //40番ピン,関数,立ち上がり
  attachInterrupt(40,Ext_ISR,RISING);
  attachTimerInterrupt(timer_ISR, T2_TIME); //タイマー割り込み
  UARTDebug.println("SetUpEnd");
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
uint timer_ISR(void) {
  UARTDebug.println("Timer_ISR");
  digitalWrite(02,HIGH);
  return T2_TIME;
}
void Ext_ISR(void)
{
  UARTDebug.println("Ext_ISR");
  digitalWrite(02, LOW);
  int sensor_v = analogRead(A3) & 0x3ff;
  UARTDebug.prinGAItf("%d\n",sensor_v);
}
```

#### 結果

Arduino IDEのシリアルモニタの出力

```
11:37:29.648 -> SetUpEnd
11:37:34.665 -> Timer_ISR
11:37:34.665 -> Ext_ISR
11:37:34.665 -> read failed:9
11:37:39.652 -> Timer_ISR
11:37:39.652 -> Ext_ISR
```

#### 備考

外部割り込みからanalogRead()を呼べるか疑問に思ったため、追加で確認しました。結果は似たようなものになりました。

#### ソースコード

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#define T2_TIME       5000000                   // Timer割り込み 5[s]
#define BAUDRATE_Debug  115200              // Debug Baud rate of UART in bps

HardwareSerial UARTDebug = Serial;    //DebugSerialのUART割当て

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  UARTDebug.begin(BAUDRATE_Debug,SERIAL_8N1);
  pinMode(02, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(02, LOW);
  pinMode(40, INPUT);
  //40番ピン,関数,立ち上がり
  attachInterrupt(40,Ext_ISR,RISING);
  UARTDebug.println("SetUpEnd");
}


void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(5000);
  digitalWrite(02, HIGH);
}



void Ext_ISR(void)
{
  UARTDebug.println("Ext_ISR");
  digitalWrite(02, LOW);
  int sensor_v = analogRead(A3) & 0x3ff;
  UARTDebug.printf("%d\n",sensor_v);
}
```

#### シリアルモニタ

```
11:48:41.653 -> SetUpEnd
11:48:46.642 -> Ext_ISR
11:48:46.676 -> read failed:9
11:48:51.658 -> Ext_ISR
11:48:56.701 -> Ext_ISR
```

Comment: こちらの質問 [SpresenseのanalogRead()の速度が非常に遅い](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/79452/) によると, 「1回の計測で15ms(プログラムでは100回で1.5秒)」らしいです (一定間隔で動作以前に)。まずは `loop()` 内で高速に動くように(各種)設定, その後に周期的動作考えてみるのがよいのでは？

Comment: ->oririrさん　コメントありがとうございます。ADC自体の速度は考慮できていませんでした。頂いたURLを参考にすると、ADCの周波数を変えられることがわかりましたので、質問の中にADC周波数を変えていることを明記します。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

[こちらに回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/85512/spresense%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6-attachtimerinrerrupt%E3%81%A8ads1115%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%B5%E7%94%A8%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E7%99%BA%E7%94%9F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8Bhard-fault%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/85517#85517)がありますが、どうも割り込みルーチンの中で analogRead は使えないみたいなんですよねェ。簡単な例ではありますが、私は次のようにして回避しました。高度な回避方法の例もリンク先にあります。ご参考まで。

```
#define TIMER_INTERVAL 1000000
bool isTimerFired = false;

uint32_t fire() {
  isTimerFired = true;
  return TIMER_INTERVAL;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  attachTimerInterrupt(fire, TIMER_INTERVAL); // 1sec
}

void loop() {
  if (isTimerFired) {
    int val = analogRead(A2);
    Serial.println("A2:" + String(val));
    isTimerFired = false;
  }
  delayMicroseconds(100);
}
```